# protocol method is not being called by the delegate object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates

Another case of protocol method not being called - NO idea what am I doing wrong here...

Here is the code, omitting unnecessary info...

first header file: AccessNumber.h

```
@protocol AddItemDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) processSuccessful: (BOOL)success;
@end

@interface AccessNumber : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {

id <AddItemDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (retain) id <AddItemDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

first .m file: AccessNumber.m - I am calling the protocol method from viewdidload just for testing purposes, it should basically get called from another method, but same thing for the sake of this convo (tried both of course)

```
#import "AccessNumber.h"
#import "History.h"

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
         [super viewDidLoad];

....

     [[self delegate] processSuccessful:YES];
}
```

second file header: History.h

```
@interface History : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AddItemDelegate> {
 ....
    }
```

method implementation in history.m

```
- (void) processSuccessful: (BOOL)success {

NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
}
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems a little bit funny but you are not telling your "AccessNumber" class who is his delegate, even though you are making the "History" class implement the protocol established by yourself (otherwise you would get a warning).

You have to set the delegate for the "AccessNumber" class like this when setting it up from within "AccessNumber.m":

```
self.delegate = historyInstance;
```

or like this when setting it up from within "History.m":

```
accessNumberInstance.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 6):

In the code i don't see something like:

```
theAccessNumber.delegate = self;
```

You must set the History instance as the delegate property of the AccessNumber instance.

Regards.

Comment: the code that i posted should be somewhere in History.m, maybe at init or viewDidLoad, that depends of you.

Answer (score 1):

There are very vew situations where you should retain a delegate, normally your delagate will outlive the object. So change your property from retain to assign. And be sure you are setting the delegate. Where are you doing it? If your object really depends on it you should be passing it in the constructor (iniWithDelagate). Try doing a NSLog before calling the delagate method just to see if it isn't nil.